# Bazel: Make bazel warnings to be treated as errors

Tags: warnings, bazel

Is there any way of treating bazel warnings (or DEBUG logs as errors when running `bazel build`?
Something similar to `-Werror` in cpp, but for Bazel itself.
For instance, when I run a build I get a warning like:

```
WARNING: Download from https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_cc/archive/0d5f3f2768c6ca2faca0079a997a97ce22997a0c.zip failed: class java.io.IOException GET returned 403 Forbidden
```

I want to treat these warnings as error in the CI server.

Comment: Could you please refer this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431850/treat-warnings-as-errors-but-ignore-warnings-in-googletest). It works as your need.

Comment: Thanks @SG_Bazel , but that's not relevant; that's about setting `-Werror` on cpp targets in Bazel. But my question is about making **Bazel** warnings fail the build as errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can treat Bazel warnings as errors when running bazel build by using the --warnings_as_errors flag. This flag will cause Bazel to treat all warnings as errors, which will cause the build to fail if any warnings are encountered.

For example:

```
bazel build --warnings_as_errors //path/to/target
```

Note that this flag is also available for other Bazel commands, such as bazel test, bazel run, and bazel query. You can use it in the same way for these commands to treat warnings as errors.